# Can you declare a variable using the type vs using var in javascript and when would it be a better option?

Tags: javascript, variables, declaration

I understand that using var to declare a variable helps prevent type conversion issues.  I searched and none of the suggested answers really apply to my question.  I looked for examples from other sites like W3Schools, but all examples use var to declare variables, but there's no real explanation for why.

```
var myVariable = 'Hello';
```

can you do the following?  And if so, when would it be a better approach than using var to declare the variable?

```
String myVariable = 'Hello';
```

Comment: There's a variation of JavaScript called `TypeScript` that allows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you do the following?  `String myVariable = 'Hello';`

### No, you can't. JavaScript is a [loosely typed language](https://medium.com/@xiaoyunyang/javascript-is-a-loosely-typed-language-meaning-you-dont-have-to-specify-what-type-of-information-137408d54fc7).

Of course, you could have found that out by just trying your second suggestion, which throws an error:

```js
String myVariable = 'Hello';
```

---

And, do yourself a favor and don't use W3Schools as it is known to have incomplete, outdated and sometimes just plain incorrect information. Instead use the [Mozilla Developer's Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). The Mozilla Foundation is the steward of the JavaScript language (after Netscape went down in flames). They are a highly recognized authority on many web languages.

Comment: Maybe you could dial back the hostile patronising tone just a teensy bit.

Comment: @Andy There is nothing at all hostile or patronizing in my answer. It contains explanations with links to additional resources as well as an example along with information on how the OP could have answered his own question.